# MySQL Update Database Where Post Values is in Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a site where users can input multiple values in the text fields, so I created an array for the post values and have successfully inserted the values of the array into the database.

I have a problem updating these values that I have stored in the database. I tried this but it's not working.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['sub_cat'])) {
    $cat_id = $_GET['c_id'];
    $subcat_title_array = $_POST['sub_cat'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($subcat_title_array); $i++) {
        $subcat_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $subcat_title_array[$i]);
        $query = "UPDATE sub_categories SET subcat_title =  '{$subcat_title}' WHERE subcat_id = $cat_id";
        $update_sub_category = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if (!$update_sub_category) {
            die("Query Failed " . mysqli_error($connection));
        }
    }          
} 
?>
```

Is there anything am doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: What happens if you run echo query and run that through php my admin?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: You're repeatedly updating the same record with `WHERE subcat_id = $cat_id`.

Comment: I echo the values am getting from the form, they displayed correctly. My problem now is updating the database.

Comment: your where clause is wrong , you updating the same record. you should have to update the record one by one using $i

Comment: You are updating the same record in the loop. So it will have the the value of late item in the array. Your category id should also be an array.

Comment: Where are you defining $connection?

Comment: @LuizEduardodeChristo I included a file at the top, the $connection is defined in that file.

Comment: Please, insert ini_set('display_errors','on') right after <?php (next line) and see if any output will be shown.